# Función: ->fetch_all(), no identificada en el servidor web:

Tags: php, mysqli, servidor

La versión de php del servidor es 5.6, la que tenía en pruebas la maquina localmente es 5.6.15. En la siguiente función trato de retornar el resultado de una consulta en un array, esta función es llamada al archivo que imprime los valores recuperados. Antes de subirlo al servidor web haciendo pruebas localmente esta función:  ->fetch_all() la estaba trabajando bien, pero en servidor web ya no, entonces intente cambiarla por las opciones comentadas en el código pero tampoco resulta, porque me sigue marcando el mismo error.

En cuanto a la versión de php, dejando la función  ->fetch_all() como la tenía originalmente, la cambie a versión 7. Pero el error seguía siendo el mismo}
Actualmente le deje la versión 5.6 e intente retornar el arreglo de diferentes formas, pero no me ha resultado, el error sigue siendo el mismo.

Error: www.plataformaceb.com no puede procesar esta solicitud en este momento.
HTTP ERROR 500

¿Que fallo sería: algo en el servidor o si es error de código como puedo sustituir la función que trabaje con la versión 5.6 de php en el servidor?

```js
<?php

 $conexion   =  conectar();

   if(isset($_GET['docte']))  

      $docente = $_GET['docte']; 

      $docentes =  getGruposByDocente($conexion,$docente);

 foreach ($docentes as $gpo): ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $gpo[0];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $gpo[1];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $gpo[2];?></td>
          <td><?php echo $gpo[3];?></td>
          <td><a href="../pdfphp/reporte.php?gpo=<?= $gpo[4]; ?>"><?php echo $gpo[0]; ?></td>
          <td>
            <a href="form_evaluaci.php?gpo=<?= $gpo[4]; ?>"><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit' ></i>CAPTURAR</button></a>
          </td>
          </tr>

          </div>

          <?php 
            endforeach;
            desconectar($conexion);
          ?>
  
            </tbody>
           </table>


?>
```

```html
function getGruposByDocente($conexion,$docente)
{
  $res = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT G.NumGpo, G.aula, G.turno, M.materia, G.idGrupo FROM materias M inner join grupos G on M.idMateria = G.materia WHERE G.profesor = $docente") or die (mysqli_error($conexion));

  $res = mysqli_fetch_array($res);  //ACTUALMENTE INTENTO

 // $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res); <-- DESPUES INTENTE CON: 
  //return $row;

//  return $res->fetch_all();   <---- ANTES TENIA ESTA FUNCION NO LA RECONOCE
}
```

Comment: Usa PHP 5.6, por lo que [`fetch_all()`](http://php.net/mysqli-result.fetch-all) debería funcionar.

Comment: la versión del servidor web es 5.6, en mi maquina el servidor local era 5.6.15. No hay mucha difrencia ahi?
 Le deje `fetch_all()` Pero me sigue marcando el mismo error

Comment: La diferencia está en que en producción no se suelen mostrar los mensajes de error, sólo en los entornos de desarrollo. Debes mirar el log de error de tu servidor apache de tu proveedor para consultar cuál es el error que te está saltando de manera silenciosa. Un error 500 no suele ser un error en tiempo de ejecución, por lo que lo más probable es que sea algún tipo de error de sintaxis o algún otro error fatal.

Comment: de acuerdo, en que parte estan esos archivos log de error?

Comment: No estoy seguro de que lo soporte tu proveedor, pero mira a ver si puedes personalizar el archivo `php.ini`. Si puedes hacerlo (o te permite modificar algunos parámetros) busca `error_reporting` para ponerlo en el valor recomendado para desarrollo (`E_ALL`) y `display_errors` a `On`. Edito: No tengo ni idea, no has dicho qué proveedor de servicios de alojamiento usas, así que no puedo adivinarlo. Mira en tu panel de cliente, debe estar en algún lado.

Comment: buscaré gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cómo estás seguro de que esa función es la que te genera el error?
El código 500 (Internal Server Error) puede ser causado por muchas razones, desde una mala conexión a la base de datos, hasta una mala configuración del servidor.  Por defecto cuando lo subes a producción, apache está configurado para no mostrar los errores, para revertir ello, puedes crear un archivo en la raíz de tu proyecto llamado: **.htaccess** y dentro de este poner las siguientes líneas:

```
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on
```

Con eso te mostrará los errores correspondientes.

Comment: de acuerdo muchas gracias